# Dynamic Facebook Meta Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

I have a site to share media posts, but I am having trouble sharing facebook posts based on what post is clicked on the page (i have a page with 20+ posts).  Is there a way of sharing the post with the correct date using the og meta tag or is my only option to use javascript to change the meta tag data?

```
<!-- Facebook -->          
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

Comment: Just a server side language like PHP, Ruby, Python or something else and generate them dynamically.

Comment: you need a "view" page that shows only one post at a url you can give to FB

Comment: Thanks Wizkid, but I am not sure how I can do this for each individual post on a single page?